# How to configure MIME type associations for Safari 5.1?

Tags: macos, safari, text-editing, mime-types

I want to edit the MIME type settings for Safari so I could use [MediaWiki's method to automatically edit text in an external editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:External_editors), or more specifically, so I can change the associated application for the `application/x-external-editor` MIME type.

Can somebody tell me if it is possible (my Google searches were pretty much fruitless) and if so, how to do it? Is it a shortcoming of Safari?

I'm on OS X by the way.

Comment: Interesting. I believe Safari notoriously ignores custom MIME types (e.g. changed through RCDefaultApp). You can list some of those it knows by going to *Help » Installed Plug-Ins*. You *might* have a chance with Firefox, but even then you'd need to find an editor that supports it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try RCDefaultApp. I think Firefox has that built-in. I've used Safari for my main browser for a long time so I wouldn't want to switch just because of this, but I've been thinking about switching anyway. I wonder how hard it would be to make a plugin for Safari that just tells it to associate MIME types with whatever.

Comment: I have already tried to use RCDefaultApp and create a custom `external-editor` MIME type. Safari still just downloads the files, e.g. when using MediaWiki and the `&externaledit=true` parameter.

Comment: @slhck Yep, it just downloads the file to the downloads folder no matter what. By the way, it sucks that creator codes (or a modern equivalent) no longer exist in Snow Leopard. I just found that out. Bad Apple! Well, the usefulness of creator codes never became a part of my workflow so it doesn't affect me that much, but it's stupid to remove that functionality completely, because it can be useful in situations like this.